# JVM long GC suspension even without exhausted memory

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

Our legacy application is running on Java 8 and using Serial Garbage Collector in the JVM. Recently we observed some unusual behavior where there was a 100% GC suspension, but the application memory was 38% and application CPU was 45%. Normally what we know is that high GC suspension can happen due to the exhausted memory. But in our case there was no such memory or CPU saturation.

[image]
[image]

Have anyone experienced such behavior in JVM and what could be the possible reasons for such behaviors.

Further analyse noticed that the Metaspace memory was saturated during the same time frame. Can this trigger GC? 
[image]

Note: We **don't** have GC logs enabled.

Comment: _We don't have GC logs enabled_, that's it. _Everything_ else is pure guessing that will take you nowhere.

Comment: Someone calling `System.gc()` in a loop?

Comment: There was no such System.gc() calls from the code.

Answer (score 0):

After deep dive into the issue the root cause has been identified. The allocated memory for metaspace was exhausted and it was not configured to auto scale. This cause the high GC suspension.